# Raspberry pi 2 not being able to connect to WI-FI

Tags: raspbian, networking, wireless

I am a beginner in world of Raspberry Pi, I have got this **Raspberry Pi 2 Model B** and i was working with Ethernet cable and now I tried to switch to WiFi but I am not able to do so.

In the latest Raspbian version there is a GUI in which we can scan the WiFi networks and just connect with correct password but every time I do so it throws an error saying *Failed to Disconnect*.
[Raspberry Pi GUI wifi connection](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/)

My files are configured as follows:

`sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` is detecting the WiFi to which I want to connect.

Here is `sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
ssid="*******"
psk="********"
proto=WPA
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
pairwise=TIKP
auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

And here is`sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

autho eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

My network is using WPA1. The Ethernet connection works without any problems

Can anybody help what exactly wrong I am doing?

Comment: How (and I might add why) are you using "static IP"?

Comment: Are you sure you have `pairwise=TIKP` in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`? As far as I know, that's invalid and probably should be `pairwise=TKIP`. Another thing you can try is comment out (place `#` in front of it) all the lines in your network block, except `ssid` and `psk`. Finally, can you add the output of `lsusb` to your question so that we can see which wifi device you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `ifconfig` to find the wlan interface. You use `wlan1`, check if it shows up after the command. If `wlan0` is the wireless interface, we configure for it.
2. Here's the walk through:
   Put this in `/etc/network/interfaces`

   ```
   auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback
   iface eth0 inet dhcp

   allow-hotplug wlan0
   iface wlan0 inet manual
   wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

   iface home inet static
   address #The-Address-You-Want-To-Use
   netmask #Mask
   gateway #gateway

   iface default inet dhcp
   ```

   And put this in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

   ```
   ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
   update_config =1
   network = {
       ssid = "Your ssid"
       scan_ssid = 1
       psk = "Your password"
       key_mgmt = WPA-PSK
       id_str = "home"
       priority = #your chosen priority
   }
   ```

`id_str="home"` is important because this is used to refer to the `iface home inet static`
`wpa-roam` puts wlan preference over ethernet.

Comment: You may want to check your answer again, because it contains a number of inconsistencies and at least one 'spelling' error

Answer (score 1):

English is not my native language so please be patient.

From one newbie to another this is what it have work for me:

First you're using dhcp in the eth0 so you can ssh your Pi, that's ok.

Let's make the changes that the link explains:

Go to `/etc/network/interfaces` and edit as it follows:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp

wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
```

Then edit your `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` as it follows:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
# ap_scan can be 0, 1, or 2. Some sources say use 2 but 1 work for me.
ap_scan=1
eapol_version=1
network={
        ssid="YOURSSID"
        # This is needed for hidden SSIDs
        scan_ssid=1
        mode=0
        psk="reallylonghexnumber"
        # RSN for WPA2 or WPA for WPA1
        proto=RSN
        # WPA-PSK or WPA-EAP
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        # CCMP for AES or TKIP for TKIP.
        pairwise=CCMP
        # OPEN for WPA1/2 or SHARED or LEAP
        auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

About the line `scan_ssid=1` will be some controversy because some more experimented users don't like the hidden ssid thing, but I repeat this works.

Hopefully this works for you also.

Sources:

https://linuxtechie.wordpress.com/2014/08/23/setting-up-raspberry-pi-with-wifi-and-a-static-ip-on-a-hidden-ssid/

https://geekytheory.com/tutorial-raspberry-pi-configurar-wif/

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you're using a decent power supply. I had a number of posts to my pi-point project about folks with Pi2s not being able to connect. After a bit of googling and checking between PiBs and the Pi2 it turned out that a weak power supply was causing errors and dropout on the USB wifi dongle on the Pi2 which caused it to fail to initialise fully as a WiFi router.

Answer (score -1):

I use archlinuxarm system, it's very easy to connect wifi.

1. install wpa_supplicant.
2. `sudo cp /etc/netctl/examples/wireless-wpa-static  /etc/netctl/wireless`
3. `sudo vim wireless ###config your wifi`
4. `netctl start wireless`

Done.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Since the question is specifically about Raspbian, suggesting how to solve with Arch Linux might not be the best of all answers ;)